# Как обратиться к ключу объекта внутри объекта?

Tags: javascript

Нужно `this.text` заменить на что то другое, только не пойму на что

```js
let obj = {
  text: 'Количество: ',
  items: this.text + 1290
};
console.log(obj.items); // Нужен результат Количество: 1290
```

Сейчас выдает `NaN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Нужно `this.text` заменить на что то другое

Нe нужно.

```js
let obj = {
  text: 'Количество: ',
  items: function() { return this.text + 1290; }
};
console.log(obj.items()); // Нужен результат Количество: 1290
```

```js
let obj = {
  text: 'Количество: ',
  get items() { return this.text + 1290; }
};
console.log(obj.items); // Нужен результат Количество: 1290
```

Совет дня:

*Чтобы обратиться к свойству объекта внутри объекта, надо сначала оказаться внутри объекта.*

Comment: Спасибо, работает!